# Proper text wrapping for right sided widget in a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a layout as follows:

[image]

**Widget1** is aligned to the left, **Widget2** and the text widget - to the right.
How can I wrap the text with an ellipsis for example in case it doesn't fit into the row, as follows?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap 'Text with property...' inside ExpandedWidget.

```
Row(
      children: [
        WidgetA(),
        WidgetB(),
        Expanded(
          child: Text("...."),
        )
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will align WidgetB to the left.

Answer (score 0):

add your Text widget inside Expanded

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text('Atras'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('Filtros offertos'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('title'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('titleasdas'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('title'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('titlesfsfsdf'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to specify MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween if you wrap every widget in the row with the same flex value. Secondly, your answer doesn't solve my question and is about something else. Please, read carefully